Dynamically generate a Flow
How can I create a Flow of switch nodes in a Group based on data loaded from a JSON file? Basically, each switch is defined in the JSON with the parameters to create the UI-Switch. The switch uses msg.payload values to populate the name, label and payload values. I have tried using a Function Node and calling on a Subflow, where the SubFlow includes one ui-switch but looping in the function is only producing the last switch device in my json file. Here is a sample of the JSON file, although in real lift, there might be as many as 20 device entries.
{
    "devices": [
        {
            "name": "device1",
            "label": "sw1",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "name": "device2",
            "label": "sw2",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "name": "device3",
            "label": "sw3",
            "value": true
        }
    ]
}

Updating original post to add example Node-Red flow and desired deployment.  In the screen shot below, I have a manually generated sample page of slider controls in a stacked list.  The label property describes room location where audio volume is being adjusted with the corresponding slider.
Node-Red sample test flow:
[
    {
        "id": "d0f133cb5a7b79e2",
        "type": "subflow",
        "name": "DynamicNode",
        "info": "",
        "category": "",
        "in": [
            {
                "x": 520,
                "y": 640,
                "wires": [
                    {
                        "id": "3890f4d5b7c9afd3"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0fecbc6a798d86f5"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "out": [],
        "env": [],
        "meta": {},
        "color": "#DDAA99"
    },
    {
        "id": "3890f4d5b7c9afd3",
        "type": "ui_text",
        "z": "d0f133cb5a7b79e2",
        "group": "bcfd32ebf2a31e62",
        "order": 3,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "name": "",
        "label": "{{\"msg.label\":\"msg.label\"}}",
        "format": "{{\"msg.text\":\"msg.text\"}}",
        "layout": "row-spread",
        "className": "",
        "style": false,
        "font": "",
        "fontSize": 16,
        "color": "#000000",
        "x": 610,
        "y": 540,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "0fecbc6a798d86f5",
        "type": "ui_switch",
        "z": "d0f133cb5a7b79e2",
        "name": "",
        "label": "{{msg.label}}",
        "tooltip": "",
        "group": "bcfd32ebf2a31e62",
        "order": 4,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "passthru": true,
        "decouple": "false",
        "topic": "topic",
        "topicType": "msg",
        "style": "",
        "onvalue": "{\"msg.switch\":true}",
        "onvalueType": "json",
        "onicon": "",
        "oncolor": "",
        "offvalue": "{\"msg.switch\":false}",
        "offvalueType": "json",
        "officon": "",
        "offcolor": "",
        "animate": false,
        "className": "",
        "x": 790,
        "y": 580,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "bcfd32ebf2a31e62",
        "type": "ui_group",
        "name": "test",
        "tab": "4ef3afefcfd15d15",
        "order": 1,
        "disp": true,
        "width": "6",
        "collapse": false,
        "className": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "4ef3afefcfd15d15",
        "type": "ui_tab",
        "name": "test",
        "icon": "question",
        "disabled": false,
        "hidden": false
    },
    {
        "id": "35c906478f19015b",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "test",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": "",
        "env": []
    },
    {
        "id": "inject",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "35c906478f19015b",
        "name": "",
        "props": [
            {
                "p": "payload"
            }
        ],
        "repeat": "",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": true,
        "onceDelay": 0.1,
        "topic": "",
        "payload": "",
        "payloadType": "date",
        "x": 570,
        "y": 460,
        "wires": [
            [
                "functionNode"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "functionNode",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "35c906478f19015b",
        "name": "Generate Subflow Instances",
        "func": "let jsonString = '[{\"text\": \"Text1\", \"switch\": true}, {\"text\": \"Text2\", \"switch\": false}, {\"text\": \"Text3\", \"switch\": true}]';\nlet definitions = JSON.parse(jsonString);\nlet outputMsgs = [];\nfor (let i = 0; i < definitions.length; i++) {\n    let msg = {\n        label: `Item ${i+1}`,\n        text: definitions[i].text,\n        switch: definitions[i].switch\n    };\n    outputMsgs.push(msg);\n}\nreturn [outputMsgs];",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 840,
        "y": 460,
        "wires": [
            [
                "dynamicNodeSubflow"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "dynamicNodeSubflow",
        "type": "subflow:d0f133cb5a7b79e2",
        "z": "35c906478f19015b",
        "name": "DynamicNodeSubflow",
        "x": 1140,
        "y": 460,
        "wires": []
    }
]

Screen shot below, represents the desired layout with slider controls being generated for each definition in JSON file above.  This page was manually created, not dynamically.


Thank you for your edits.  I will also edit the post and add my existing test.

There is nothing that will do this for you, you are going to need to write code to parse the input data and output a flow JSON object.
You will then need to use the Node-RED Admin API to deploy this flow.
Writing self modifying Node-RED flows is possible, but very easy to mess up and leave you with an un-runnable flow. I suggest you start with writing this as a separate stand alone app first, before trying to build a self modifying flow

You might be able to achieve the result you are looking for with the node-red-contrib-custom-chatgpt node. There is an example included that is used to generate individual nodes as a flow.json that are importable into the editor (manually or automatic). With some trial and error you could set up a template node that configures it to do multiple nodes for a flow at once while following your custom instructions to parse the incoming JSON file. You will likely want to verify the outputs before using them every time.
Unfortunately this solution does require an API key from OpenAI.
